# Storyboard - Unsupported configuration 8 conflicting constrains

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am using storyboard autolayout. I am noticing today, while compiling a warning message

```
MainStoryboard_iphone.storyboard
Unsupported Configuration
8 conflicting constraints
```

Clicking on warning takes to storyboard, but not to view which is a problem. Is there a way to figure out which view/control has the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Right click on the "8 conflicting constraints" and select "Reveal in log". There should be a line with something like the following in your log:

/path/to/storyboard/Storyboard_iPad.storyboard:8or-pl-jNO: warning: 2 conflicting constraints

The part between the colons between the storyboard path and the warning (8or-pl-jNO in my case) is the ID of the constraint that caused the issue.

To find the constraint, right click on your storyboard file in the project navigator, then Open As -> Source Code, then search for the ID of the constraint. You should then be able to find what View it is contained in in the XML, then you can switch back to Interface Builder (Open As -> Interface Build - iOS Storyboard), then find the view that contained the constraint, and find the constraint that caused the problem. You can select the constraints in the document outline, then check their ID in the Identity Inspector at the right hand side, under the Document section, named Object ID.

Comment: You are amazing. I just went the painful route by removing one by one and fixed it. I cannot validate this moment. But will do so in the evening and accept your answer

Comment: I could not open in log, but using the pop put view in interface builder i disabled the constraints that were point to unsed views in the particular design layout ie landscape view. If you click on the constraint, then click on the "size inspector" and scroll right to the bottom, there is an option with an installed check box clicked. Leave that, but you want to click the small + to add current view you are looking at as an option, which once added you want to uncheck. Long winded but hope it helps someone.

Comment: You could also just find the constraint ID in the "find in project" (cmd-shift-F) and just click it to find which constraint it is.

Comment: This is just so sad. :(

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew Porritt 's answer not work in my case, I use Xcode 6. The warning reads:

```
"Unsupported Configuration of constraint attributes. This may product unexpected results at runtime and is not compatible with Xcode versions prior to 5.1"

"Attribute Unavaliable" (e.g. I use preferred max layout width)
```

I can't open the log file, what I did is open the storyboard file as source code, so the warnings will appear at the corresponding line(just like shown as in the .swift/.m source code)